# IsClippedToBounds does not work in xamarin form

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I used `Frame` and `IsClippedToBounds` to add `cornerRadius` to my image but it does not work.

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="White" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0">
     <Image Source="House.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
</Frame>
```

[image]

Comment: how is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is supposed to work , this is running screenshot on my side with your code .

[image]

I'm not aware of the cause but as a woakround you can use `ImageButton` instead of `Frame + Image`.

The usage is pretty simple

```
<ImageButton Aspect="AspectFill" CornerRadius="10" IsEnabled="False" Source="House.jpg"/>
```